# I need to pull data out of this array into variables

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, which I have created by importing a csv file with the parsecsv library.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [cubcode] => EC023 [qty] => 2 )
    [1] => Array ( [cubcode] => EC026A [qty] => 3 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [cubcode] => EC025 [qty] => 7 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [cubcode] => EC027 [qty] => 67 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [cubcode] => EC031 [qty] => 567 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [cubcode] => EC033 [qty] => 78 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [cubcode] => EC034 [qty] => 234 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [cubcode] => EC038 [qty] => 67 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [cubcode] => EC038A [qty] => 67 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [cubcode] => EC039 [qty] => 60 ) 
    [10] => Array ( [cubcode] => EC039A [qty] => 100 )
)
```

I need to loop through the array to create two variables "cubcode" and "qty" and use them in a function that I have already created.

I am struggling to get to them because the seem to be nested in the array.  I have not done much work with arrays, so please be gentle with me.

Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to tackle this problem. What have you tried? Maybe take a look at the [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Comment: @SeanBright I understand your frustration.  However, I had tried a number of things and spent a few hours searching for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the code only answer, but you literally just need to write it in PHP, and not in English. Since `$csv->data` (from comments) is the name of the array:

```
foreach ($csv->data as $item) {
  function_you_already_created($item['cubcode'], $item['qty']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I already tried something like that.

     `$csv = new ParseCsv\Csv();
     $csv->auto($destination);
     print_r($csv->data);
     foreach ($csv as $row) {
      $database->update_stock_log($row['cubcode'],$row['qty'],"1234");

     }
`

Comment: Did you try `foreach ($csv->data as $row)` ?

Comment: Thank you. That was my problem.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Great. For future questions, please put one example of what you tried in the question itself. You'll get faster and better answers; and no coding service comments.